# Magento 2.4 Error: The attribute 'length' is not allowed

Tags: db-schema

I want to change the field type of catalogrule_product table from varchar to text.

```
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="action_operator" nullable="true" length="10" default="to_fixed"
                comment="Action Operator"/>
```

For this first I overrided db_schema.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="catalogrule_product" resource="default" >
<column xsi:type="text" name="action_operator" nullable="true" default="to_fixed"
                comment="Action Operator"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

But when I'm doing the setup:upgrade I'm getting the below error:

```
Invalid Document 
Element 'column', attribute 'length': The attribute 'length' is not allowed.
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I can't delete that field because it makes data loss in the field.

Comment: Same issue here...

Comment: If the "lenght" error is related to the same attribute, it means there is another db_schema.xml in another module (probably the original declaration of the field). Magento tried to merge the xml attributes to preserve _upgradability_, but they didn't predicted this type of scenario I guess. I had the same issue here, and ended up by manually modifying the original db_schema.xml file instead. =/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove `length` and `default` from the `text` type.

It only takes `nullable` attribute.

See this:

```
<xs:complexType name="text">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="abstractColumnType">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Here plain text can be persisted. Length of this field is more than 255 characters
                    and less than 65536
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>

            <xs:attribute name="nullable" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

So it will become this:

```
<column xsi:type="text" name="action_operator" nullable="true" comment="Action Operator"/>
```

Comment: I have removed default also, but still the issue there

Comment: Is it the same error? If it is then it must be coming from another place.